# Contribution Export Places Campaign IDs in Campaign Title Column, Nothing in Campaign ID Column

Tags: civicontribute

When we search for contributions and export, the export places Campaign IDs in Campaign Title column and nothing in Campaign ID Column. Any ideas?

CiviCRM 4.6.3 (happened in older versions also)

WP 4.2.2

Thanks,

e.

[image: Screen grab of missing data]

Comment: Update: I was able to recreate this on the official Civi 4.6 WP demo site.

Comment: For anybody trying to reproduce the link to the demo site's user who has a contribution with a campaign assigned: http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/view&reset=1&cid=123

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I can also reproduce the issue - on the WP and the Drupal demo site. Interesting enough, for "Select Fields to Export" there is only one option "Campaign" in the list which results in two columns "Campaign ID" and "Campaign Title" in the exported csv file.

Comment: Agreed. I was advised to submit a bug report on JIRA and did so yesterday. Hopefully, this can be easily sorted.

Comment: Eric, could you provide a link to your bug report?

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16534

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Please file an issue on JIRA referencing this page. Instructions on filing a bug report here: https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting